# What is the proper way to create a Pandas DataFrame from MongoEngine result?

Tags: dataframe, mongoengine

I can do the following to get a data frame.

```
json_data = DocumentClass.objects(some_field=some_value).to_json()
df = json_normalize(json.loads(json_data))
```

But it involves creating an intermediate json object which is not necessary. If anybody knows a better way, please share.

Answer (score 0):

I use the "_cursor" property of the QuerySet.
Try

```
mongoengine_cursor = DocumentClass.objects(some_field=some_value)._cursor
df = pd.DataFrame(mongoengine_cursor)
```